# Someone else's muktzeh on the table

Tags: muktzeh

I come to Shul and on the Table is an Mp3 player. Can I sit at the table or is it a problem because the Table is now A  Bosis Ldovir Hamutzah?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this one the hint gives it away you can not make Assur comthing that is not yours hence here this item does not accomplish anything it dosent make a bosis since you can only make your own stuff a bosis

Answer (score 2):

Many people light the Shabbos candles at the table and then sit at it to eat their meal. I know that they often leave a Siddur or something else which is not Muktze at the table too. However as far as I know even if they did not leave a non Muktze item at the table, they can still eat at the table, they just can not move it.